# ASP.net MVC5 accessing button in view from controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Hey all I'm new to MVC so here is my question I'm stuck on:

How do I set a button on my view False for visible from the controller?

My view code for the button is:

```
<Button class="btn btn-primary btn-large btnCustom5" id="AdminMode">Admin Mode</Button>
```

And my controller code is:

```
public ActionResult getMainData()
{
  //More code up here....

  if (Permissions == "ADMIN") {
       AdminMode.Visible = True;
  } else {
     AdminMode.Visible = False;
  }

  //More code down here....
}
```

But the code above doesn't seem to "see" the AdminMode button that's on the view?

How/what do I need to do in order for me to change the button?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You hide things in your view using razor.

```
@if(Model.Admin.Visible)
{
<Button class="btn btn-primary btn-large btnCustom5" id="AdminMode">Admin Mode</Button>
}
```

Just make sure you are passing it in using your model.

Model:

```
public class Model
{
public Admin{get; set;}
}
```

A view model is essentially just a container class where you pass view specific information to your view.

Other approaches would be using ViewData/Viewbag(They're the same thing), which is just another way to pass data into your view.

Controller:

```
ViewBag.IsAdmin == true;
```

View:

```
@if(ViewBag.IsAdmin)
{
<Button class="btn btn-primary btn-large btnCustom5" id="AdminMode">Admin Mode</Button>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, Jesse. Can you also show what the model would look like since I am not using that?

Comment: I've updated the post a couple times. Do you need any more clarification?

Answer (score 3):

MVC is a bit different than WebForms. You actually don't have a control tree on the server, so you cannot access any of the elements in your controller. What you can do is add a value to your `ViewBag` in the controller, and change the button visibility according to that value.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult getMainData()
{
  //More code up here....

  if (Permissions == "ADMIN") {
     ViewBag.AdminMode = True;
  } else {
     ViewBag.AdminMode = False;
  }

  //More code down here....
}
```

View:

```
@if (ViewBag.AdminMode) {
    <Button class="btn btn-primary btn-large btnCustom5" id="AdminMode">Admin Mode</Button>
}
```

Comment: So I do not need to use a model with this example?

Comment: @StealthRT nope. But you should since the first letter in MVC is Model

Comment: ViewBag would be the easiest, quickest option as @Steve points out, but understand that if you have a form and an action to handle the form post, then you may have to reset the ViewBag variable if there's a form error or if you just want to render the view again. In which case, Jesse Moreland's original answer would be a better choice.